# How to convert array of composite type to array of java objects with jdbc and Postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have an array of composite type. Let's say it looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE hobbie AS (
  name VARCHAR,
  description VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE person (
    id SERIAL,
    hobbie hobbie[]
);
```

Now I need to retrieve hobbies of person from postgres and convert them into java object which looks like this:

```
public class Hobbie {
    String name;
    String description;
}
```

The only thing which I was able to do with jdbc is to convert array get to result set with hobbies as String like this `("basketball","the best game")`. How can I convert it to java object using jdbc?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my code to work with postgres array using jdbc:

```
ResultSet hobbies = rs.getArray("hobbies").getResultSet
while (hobbies.next()){
    hobbies.getString(1) // returns some index or I don't know
    hobbies.getObject(2) // returns PgValue with value == String ("basketball","the best game")
    hobbies.getObject(2)  // obviously returns String with the same value
    hobbies.getArray(2)   // returns something strange
    hobbies.getObject(2, Hobbie.class) // throws unsupported conversion to class com.test.Hobbie. Maybe there is a way to register custom converter, but I didn't find any
 }
```

Comment: And the code you used to convert the array is...?

Comment: I added a new answer containing a way to tackle this issue from the SQL query end

Comment: The JDBC driver returns composite types as strings. There is no feature to register any conversion from composite types to Java beans

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, but I would be able easily convert it by myself if only it was not a String, but a ResultSet or something like this, e.g. something with methods getString(name or index), getLong(...) and so on.

Comment: As I said: the driver returns a String. A `java.sql.Struct` would probably be better (and adhere to the JDBC specs), but it currently does not do that. If you need that, you will need to implement it your self. I'm sure the driver's developers would be happy about a patch doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the table like this

```
SELECT (r).* FROM (SELECT unnest(hobbie) AS r 
from person) AS hobbies;
```

It'll output the hobbies as if they were a table. JDBC translation should rather straight-forward from there.

Comment: You can also use `(r).*`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, I refined my answer :)

Comment: I think that this is the correct idea. Anyway, there's a shorter syntax: `select id, (unnest(hobbie)).* from person` (also returns the ID, which I assume would be necessary to create the relation in memory).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works and I ended up with the same solution, but I was wondering if there is a way to convert hobbies without subquery and unnesting using bare jdbc.

Comment: @ArtemMalinko please accept my if it helped. Again - if it's custom OM which you are trying to achieve, I'd highly recommend  JOOQ,  which allows you to build and run any query you  like and then just bind the results into any JPA annotated POJO.

Comment: @Sheinbergon not exactly. jOOQ does not support arbitrarily nested objects. It supports POJOs only at a single level of nesting.